# iOS Programming, Xcode 6.1.1. Error: Data file 'library.a-x86_64.fin' does not exist. Finalizing - Failed

Tags: ios, ios-app-group, xcode6.1.1

I am using third party library files which contains .h, static library (.a), .fin, .key files. The readme says:
**1)** .fin, .key & .a files should be present on same location.
**2)** Add flags "-finalize -prefinalized-library library_name.a" in "Other Linker Flags" option.
**3)** Click Yes on "Write Link Map File" option.

I have created a new group/folder in the project from the "Xcode's Project Navigator" window & placed .a, .key, .fin files  & followed the same steps as mentioned & when I was trying to compile the application, .fin files were not found during linking.

When I removed the "Other Linker Flags option" the application was getting compiled. But the readme says "Other Linker Flags option" is mandatory for using the library.

Apart from this. When I copied .a, .key, .fin files without creating any folder then the application compiles successfully. But if these files are placed inside a folder in the application then application fails to compile.

Can anyone please help me on this. How & where to provide the path to .key, .fin files so that the application gets compiled using the finalizer.

Xcode 6.1.1
iOS SDK version 8.1
OS X - Yosemite 10.10.2

Comment: Is there no one to answer this?? Guys pls help!
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved by adding the flag -Wfin-data-files {PATH}. The path is where Xcode can find the .fin files